# I'd like to enumerate a list with a decimal

Tags: numbering, lists, enumerate

He guys.  I currently have this...

```
\newlist{Problem}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[Problem]{label=Problem-\arabic*:}
```

That will give me lists 1-n. What I want is actually 1.1 - 1.n.  Is there a way to change this so that it only increments the decimal value?

Comment: What does `1` in `1.n` represent?

Comment: sorry - so if I have 3 "Problems", i'd like it to be 1.1, 1.2, 1.3.  The one in the ones place (1.x) will never change

Comment: And where does the 1 come from? I guess it is another counter.

Answer (score 4):

You can just add the `1.` prefix to your `label`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{Problem}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[Problem]{label={Problem-1.\arabic*:},leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}

Here are some problems:

\begin{Problem}
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \item Last item
\end{Problem}

\end{document}
```